# How to prevent page from refreshing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_donorType" runat="server" 
 AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="rbl_donorType_SelectedIndexChanged" >
```

How to prevent page from refreshing(F5), I need the autopostback command. Thanks :)

Comment: not sure what you are asking here. When you set the autopostback true, it will "refresh" the page but actually perform a POST request. if you don't want it to do that then just don't set the autopostback property but of course it wont postback then. what are you exactly looking for here?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UpdatePanel`s. They do partial postback, not full page refreshing.